# Why is my bootstrap clearfix breaking in my Rails collection?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a student working on my final project. Below you will see two screen-shots of my application. The first is the normal desktop view, where everything is rendered correctly. As you begin to resize the view-port smaller, the position of items becomes uneven as you can see in the second screen shot.

Am I using the clearfix incorrectly for Bootstrap? I attempted to place the clearfix underneath each vehicle but then realized from checking the Bootstrap documentation that the clearflix class must wrap around said items. Below is my code:

**vehicles/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">


<!-- Side Column -->
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <h3 class="item-category">Make: </h3>
    <ul class="side-menu">
      <%= form_tag filter_vehicles_path do |f| %>
        <% Vehicle.makes.each do |make| %>
            <li>
              <%= display_chosen_check_box_tag(make, params[:makes], "makes[]") -%>
              <%= make -%>
            </li>
        <% end %>

  <h3 class="item-category">Year: </h3>
        <% Vehicle.year_ranges.each do |range| %>
            <li>
              <%= display_chosen_check_box_tag(range, params[:years], "years[]") -%>
              <%= range -%>
            </li>
        <% end %>

        <li><%= submit_tag "Filter" %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Body Column -->
  <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bottom">
              <h3 class="item-title"><%= link_to "#{vehicle.make} #{vehicle.model}", vehicle %></h3>
                <%= image_tag(vehicle.primary_image.image_url, class: "img-responsive") if vehicle.primary_image %>
                <p class="index-info"><%= vehicle.user.name %>'s <%= vehicle.year %> <%= vehicle.make %> <%= vehicle.model %></p>
                <%= link_to "View Details", vehicle, class: "item-more" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**the loop in question**

```
<!-- Body Column -->
  <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bottom">
              <h3 class="item-title"><%= link_to "#{vehicle.make} #{vehicle.model}", vehicle %></h3>
                <%= image_tag(vehicle.primary_image.image_url, class: "img-responsive") if vehicle.primary_image %>
                <p class="index-info"><%= vehicle.user.name %>'s <%= vehicle.year %> <%= vehicle.make %> <%= vehicle.model %></p>
                <%= link_to "View Details", vehicle, class: "item-more" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Regards.

[image: Full view]

[image: Tablet view]

Comment: You are using `.clearfix` incorrectly. The primary and most common use of such class is to put an empty `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after all elements that have a `float:left` property. I would suggest to remove the `.clearfix` entirely and search how to make your `.col-sm-6` of same height. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height), you might find the answers provided helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add too much of javascript and and clearfix and all. We just need to have tweak in css.
You just need to add `min-height` to items. Everything will be solved. I have created a fiddle for you.
In fiddle:
 **Demo1** is your scenerio and **demo2** is the fixed scenerio.
try resizing the viewport to see the effect on demo1 and demo 2.

https://jsfiddle.net/Anuj_Kumar/sc17mzkp/1/

If still your problem is not solved just let me know i will solve that too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your body code with following structure for your resolve issue. You will need to add `clearfix` class after every 2 item.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="item-layout">
            <div class="item">Your content</div>
            <div class="item">Your content</div>
            <span class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></span>
            <div class="item">Your content</div>
            <div class="item">Your content</div>
            <span class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></span>
            <div class="item">Your content</div>
            <div class="item">Your content</div>
            <span class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></span>
            <div class="item">Your content</div>
            <div class="item">Your content</div>
            <span class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

According to your code, You have set 2 column(2 item) in per row. So, You will need to add `clearfix` class after every 2 item. but, Here, Your code is dynamic with loop. So, Here, You will need to add `clearfix` class dynamic every 2 item. So, You will add dynamic `clearfix` class with jquery according screen view.

**Try following instruction with your code.**

First of all, add `item-layout` class in your main item div. also, add `item` class in your loop div. following example.

```
<!-- Body Column -->
  <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="item-layout">
          <% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bottom item">
              <h3 class="item-title"><%= link_to "#{vehicle.make} #{vehicle.model}", vehicle %></h3>
                <%= image_tag(vehicle.primary_image.image_url, class: "img-responsive") if vehicle.primary_image %>
                <p class="index-info"><%= vehicle.user.name %>'s <%= vehicle.year %> <%= vehicle.make %> <%= vehicle.model %></p>
                <%= link_to "View Details", vehicle, class: "item-more" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

also, **add following jquery** for add dynamic `<span class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></span>` for clearfix.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$screensize = $(window).width();
    if ($screensize > 1199) {
        $(".item-layout > .clearfix").remove();
        $('.item-layout .item:nth-child(2n)').after('<span class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></span>');
    }
    if ($screensize < 1199) {
        $(".item-layout > .clearfix").remove();
        $('.item-layout .item:nth-child(2n)').after('<span class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-md-block"></span>');
    }
    if ($screensize < 991) {
        $(".item-layout > .clearfix").remove();
        $('.item-layout .item:nth-child(2n)').after('<span class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-sm-block"></span>');
    }
$( window ).resize(function() {
    $screensize = $(window).width();
    if ($screensize > 1199) {
        $(".item-layout > .clearfix").remove();
        $('.item-layout .item:nth-child(2n)').after('<span class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></span>');
    } 
    if ($screensize < 1199) {
        $(".item-layout > .clearfix").remove();
        $('.item-layout .item:nth-child(2n)').after('<span class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-md-block"></span>');
    }
    if ($screensize < 991) {
        $(".item-layout > .clearfix").remove();
        $('.item-layout .item:nth-child(2n)').after('<span class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-sm-block"></span>');
    }
    if ($screensize < 767) {
        $(".item-layout > .clearfix").remove();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is a really great idea to a very common problem in Ruby on Rails apps where we use the block function to paginate our object with multiple bootstrap classes, for example `col-xs-12` `col-sm-6` `col-md-4` as we will need the `clearfix` in different places depending on screen size.  Creating a `min-height` css rule does not always result in aesthetically pleasing web design.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Body Column -->
  <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bottom" style="display: -webkit-flex;display: flex;">
              <h3 class="item-title"><%= link_to "#{vehicle.make} #{vehicle.model}", vehicle %></h3>
                <%= image_tag(vehicle.primary_image.image_url, class: "img-responsive") if vehicle.primary_image %>
                <p class="index-info"><%= vehicle.user.name %>'s <%= vehicle.year %> <%= vehicle.make %> <%= vehicle.model %></p>
                <%= link_to "View Details", vehicle, class: "item-more" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

add this style="display: -webkit-flex;display: flex;".
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your object heights are uneven. You're looking for a grid-style substitute given that you have an expectation to have these items reflow on resize.

I'd recommend using a CSS Flexbox layout on your collection container.

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

[Here's a demonstration.](http://codepen.io/richseviora/pen/bVKMdL)

The other problem (as HarnishDesign noted) is that your use of the clearfix is incorrect. It puts everything after on a whole new line because it's using the `clear: both` rule. Read up on the clear rule [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear).

**Edit 1**

It's worth noting that the Flexbox properties are not standardized yet, but there is wide support for them.